# Sitecore 8 Speak UI QueryDataSource in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-speak-ui

I am trying to access QueryDatasource results in Javascript. Everything is setup correctly. I get the items by using

```
var destData = this.regionQueryDatasource.get("items");
```

My issue is that,

1. I want to get those items on page load. I put this code inside initialize() then it doesn't return anything. If I call it in some button click function, then it returns data.

   ```
     initialized: function () {
     var destData = this.regionQueryDatasource.get("items");},
   ```
2. I want the querying to happen in synchronous manner. Sometimes, the items are returned as empty. I want to wait till the items are loaded.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I ask what you are doing your doing with the results? Are you binding them to a SPEAK grid or other SPEAK control?

Comment: Where do you use the initialized function, in the extended ControlModel or the extended  ControlView ??

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I want to get Region, Resort, Hotel data using QueryDatasource for each and then join the results, pass it to Jsondatasource and then display in the grid.

Comment: So, I want to wait till I get items from all the above 3 datasources and then process them in some method. I hope that answers your query.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried refreshing the DataSource before calling Get items?

E.g

```
 this.regionQueryDatasource.refresh()
```

Then you can check `viewModel.hasItems()`

Id recommend using `this.regionQueryDatasource.viewModel.items()` rather than `this.regionQueryDatasource.get("items")`;